# How can I horizontally center a letter in CSS ignoring kerning (considering only glyph edges)?

Tags: css, fonts, glyph, kerning

I'm very doubtful this is possible but I'd like to center a single letter (within a circle) considering only the horizontal edges of the glyph.

In particular the uppercase `J` in [Droid Sans](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Droid+Sans) is kerned such that the vertical bar is centered, but the tail extends out to the left. E.g. if you select the letter, the tail leaves the surrounding box.

I've tried all the CSS properties/values I could find, including `font-kerning` and other CSS3 drafts, the `::first-letter` selector, etc. in Chrome and Firefox.

```css
div {
  font-family: "Droid Sans";
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  font-size: 40px;
  line-height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #ddd;
}
div + div {
  font-family: Arial
}
```

```html
<head>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Droid+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
Droid Sans:
<div>J</div>
Arial (desired centering):
<div>J</div>
```

Comment: and your code is?

Comment: It will be very helpful if you make (jsfiddle)[jsfiddle.net]

Comment: You might need to revert to using a bitmap/gif/jpg of what you want to see.

Comment: If what you're asking to do is force a variable width font to behave like a monospaced font with only CSS, then no.  Although there are some JS projects out there that aim to accomplish this.

Comment: @dippas [**demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/rickyruizm/bhvf8j0n/) Check the ::selection.

Comment: I've added a snippet. @RicardoRuiz I doubt flex centering will fix this.

Comment: All fonts have their quirks (read _glyph sizes_), designed one's especially, and they all need a manual touch, like in this case, as you can't read from the font (in a practical way) where the actual letter is positioned internally.

Comment: @SteveClay I was just providing a demo, not a solution.

Comment: I clarified in the Q that I was looking for a general solution, so I don't have to calculate manual per-character offsets by hand.

Comment: Respectfully, cmon. If this question were really "how to position a letter to the left a bit", it would've been closed due to a million duplicates or given a simple answer. I'd rather delete the Q.

Comment: @LGSon You really think it's reasonable from the original Q that I didn't know about `letter-spacing`, or `position: relative`, or `text-indent` or maybe dozens of other ways to hardcode an offset? My edit was not intentioned to rob you of karma.

Comment: Sure, they can be deleted

Comment: Is it against policy to add an addendum? Without clarification I don't see how this adds any community value.

Comment: If it invalidates already given answers, it is against policy.